# TAdoDataSet, TAdoStoredProc multiple result sets

Tags: sql-server, delphi, ado

These components have the ability to retrieve multiple result sets (e.g. from a stored proc) in one go, and using D5 I can successfully use NextRecordSet to get at the second and subsequent ones from a Sql Server.

However, this *only* works if I specify the cursor location as clClient; if I use clServer, I get a "Does not return multiple result sets" error.  Is this an inherent limitation (e.g imposed by the MDac layer on the client) or can multiple recordsets be successfully retrieved from a server-side cursor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an inherent limitation to server side cursors. As stated in following [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905899%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx):

> Server cursors cannot be used with statements that generate more than
>   one recordset.
>
> This restriction applies to all statements described in Generating
>   Multiple Recordsets. For more information, see [Generating Multiple
>   Recordsets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905897%28v=sql.80%29.aspx). If a server cursor is used with any statement that
>   generates multiple recordsets, an application can return one of the
>   following errors:
>
> - Cannot open a cursor on a stored procedure that has anything other than a single SELECT statement in it.
> - sp_cursoropen. The statement parameter can only be a single SELECT statement or stored procedure.